# android - how to read a specific number of bytes from socket?

Tags: java, android, sockets, msgpack

In my system, I am using tcp to transfer messages between an android application, and a desktop application (that is developed in Qt).

I am using `msgpack` library to serialize/deserialize structures in both applications. In order to make sure that the structure is always received as a whole, I always send the number of bytes (encoded as a 32-bit big endian unsigned integer not using `msgpack` so that it always takes the first 4 bytes) before the message itself (that is encoded in `msgpack`). If there is a better way please tell me.

In the android app, I read the first 4 bytes into a `byte[]` and decode it into a `long msgSize`, next I need a way for the thread to keep blocking until the next `msgSize` bytes are received. After reading other questions and answers, I think I can write something like this:

```
InputStream is= sock.getInputStream();
byte[] msgSizeBuff= new byte[4];
is.read(msgSizeBuff, 0, 4);
long msgSize= MyDecodeFunction(msgSizeBuff);
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(is);
byte[] msg = new byte[msgSize];
dis.readFully(msg);
```

After that I can use the msg array with msgpack, and I am sure that the whole message is received.

So:

1. is my usage of `DataInputStream` class alright, and am I guranteed that I will wait until I receive the specified number of bytes? because in the [reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/DataInputStream.html) they say:

> If insufficient bytes are available, EOFException is thrown.

2. I want a way to tell this thread to cancel the operation, so what would happen if another thread calls `socket.close()` or `socket.shutdownInput()`, will I get an exception?

Comment: Think it will not work with readFully. Untested. I would make a small buffer and in a loop fill that buffer. Count the bytes you readed. At last read the remaining bytes. Transfer the bytes in that buffer to msg.

Comment: why don't you use dis.available() to see how many bytes have you receive, and wait more if not enough?

Comment: For reading to byte array you don't need DataInputStream. Just use msgSize=is.available(), then is.read(msg) or is.read(mgs, 0, msgSize), andd that should be all right.

Comment: @greenapps, I am now writing your approach, haven't tested it yet, but I think it should work

Comment: @Gavriel,in the [reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FilterInputStream.html#available%28%29) `available()` might not be safe.

Comment: So basically what the reference recommends " Such callers should probably write everything they read to a ByteArrayOutputStream and convert that to a byte array" is the same as @greenapps suggested

Comment: @cyanide, I want to make sure the whole message is received on my side before starting to parse, if I set `msgSize=is.available()`, I am assuming the message has not been fragmented while it is being transmitted, and that may lead to later exceptions since that may not be always true. . .

Comment: @greenapps, yes :) and that's what I am trying now :)